# Subtracting Random numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm making a game where the user must solve a simple subtraction but the result must be a positive whole number. I managed to do everything but for some reason the answer is sometimes negative and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Subtraction {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    final int MAX = 10;
    // get two random numbers between 1 and MAX
    int num1 = r.nextInt(MAX) - 1;
    int num2 = r.nextInt(MAX) - 1;

    int total = (num1 - num2);

    // display a question
    System.out.printf("What is your answer to %d - %d = ?%n", num1, num2);

    // read in the result
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ans = stdin.nextInt();
    stdin.nextLine();

    // give an reply
    if (ans == total) {
      System.out.println("You are correct!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Sorry, wrong answer!");
      System.out.printf("The answer is %d + %d = %d%n", num1, num2, (num1 - num2));
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:  Just change your total line with a condition to subtract the larger one from the smaller one (unless they're the same, in which case you'll get 0)

```
 int total = (num1 > num2) ? (num1 - num2) : (num2 - num1);
```

Or just use the absolute value:

```
 int total = java.lang.Math.abs(num1 - num2);
```

Change the printf as well:

```
 System.out.printf("What is your answer to %d - %d = ?%n", (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2, (num1 > num2) ? num2 : num1);
```

The conditionals are just making sure that the bigger number comes before the smaller number, or if they happen to be equal, that they are both listed.

Check out http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html for a more thorough explanation of the ? operator.

Answer (score 1):

Generate your first value with room at the bottom for a second value to be subtracted, and the second one from a range bounded by the first:

```
int num1 = r.nextInt(MAX - 1) + 2;  // produces values from 2 to MAX, inclusive
int num2 = r.nextInt(num1 - 1) + 1; // produces values from 1 to (num1 - 1), inclusive
```

The first number will always be strictly larger than the second, by construction, so the difference will always be a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with two random numbers in the same range, in random order, either cold be larger and the subtraction could be negative. Either fix how you get the numbers, or fix how they are ordered, or fix how you get their difference; any of these will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the result must be positive, I would start with the result

```
int total = r.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
int num2 = r.nextInt(MAX - total + 1);

int num1 = total + num2;
```

This way you can be sure that `num1 - num2` will always be positive.

Comment: After doing this one of the random numbers was 4- (-1). Im not sure how the negative one got there

Comment: It's a nice workaround - but it's very likely `num1` will exceed `MAX` (e.g.: `MAX = 10, total = 9, num2 = 3 => num1 = 12 > MAX`).

Comment: @Brandon.O Note that I changes `- 1` to `+ 1`

Answer (score 0):

The code at the very heart of your program is wrong:

```
// get two random numbers between 1 and MAX
int num1 = r.nextInt(MAX) - 1;
int num2 = r.nextInt(MAX) - 1;
```

`r.nextInt(MAX)` returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and `MAX` (exclusive). Your code *subtracts* one from it, so you get a number in the range `[−1, MAX−2]`.

Since you want it to be a simple subtraction where all numbers are in the range `[1, MAX]`, you have to generate them that way. The general form of the subtraction is:

```
result = num1 − num2
```

This equation has the following constraints:

- `1 <= result <= MAX`
- `1 <=   num1 <= MAX`
- `1 <=   num2 <= MAX`
- `result < MAX`, since otherwise `num2` would have to be `0`
- `1 < num1`, since otherwise the result would become negative
- `num2 < MAX`, since otherwise `result` would have to be larger than `MAX`

This leaves the following allowed ranges:

- `1 <= result <= MAX − 1`
- `2 <=   num1 <= MAX`
- `1 <=   num2 <= MAX − 1`
- `num2 <= num1 - 1`

To generate these numbers, the code has to look like this:

```
int num1 = randomBetween(2, MAX);
int maxNum2 = Math.min(MAX - 1, num1 - 1);
int num2 = randomBetween(1, maxNum2);
```

Now what is `randomBetween`? You have to define it:

```
randomBetween(min, max) ≡ r.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min
```

Together, this is:

```
int num1 = r.nextInt(MAX + 1 - 2) + 2;
int maxNum2 = Math.min(MAX - 1, num1 - 1);
int num2 = r.nextInt(maxNum2 + 1 - 1) + 1;
int result = num1 - num2;
assert 1 <= result && result <= MAX;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package optinalTest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Subtraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            randomNumber();
        }

    }

    private static void randomNumber() {
        // get two random numbers between 1 and MAX
        int num1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000, 9999998);
        int num2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(num1 + 1, 9999999);

        int total = (num2 - num1);

        // display a question
        System.out.printf("What is your answer to %d - %d = ?%n", num2, num1);

        // read in the result
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ans = stdin.nextInt();
        stdin.nextLine();

        // give an reply
        if (ans == total) {
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, wrong answer!");
            System.out.printf("The answer is %d - %d = %d%n", num2, num1, (num2 - num1));
        }
    }
}
```